# GET switch to string

Tags: php, switch-statement, swiftmailer

So i am getting a value from my `$_GET` for example `403` and I'm mailing it. But i want to if get returns 403 it will return `sent` in the mail.

```
   <?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

switch($_GET['status'])
{
    case 403:
        echo 'sent';
        break;
}
switch($_GET['status'])
{
    case 404:
        echo 'delivered';
        break;
}

if (!empty($_GET['MsgId'])) {
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('xxx', xxx))
        ->setUsername('xxx')
        ->setPassword('xxx');

    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

    $message = (new Swift_Message('Status SMS ' . $_GET['MsgId'] . '.'))
        ->setFrom(['xxx' => 'xxx'])
        ->setTo(['xxx' => 'xxx', 'xxx' => 'xxx'])
        ->setBody("ID Wiadomości : " . $_GET['MsgId'] . "Status Wiadomości" . $_GET['status'] . ".");

    $result = $mailer->send($message);

    echo 'OK';
}
else {
    echo 'Coś nie śmigło.';
}
exit;
```

Switch doesn't work for me.

Comment: That's not how switch works :)

Comment: You are using your `switch` statement as if it is an `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not changing the global variable `$_GET['status']` by using `echo`, and I don't think you should be, use a variable instead :

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
// we set a variable to hold the status code
$status = '';
switch($_GET['status'])
{
    case 403:
        $status =  'sent';
        break;
    case 404:
        $status = 'delivered';
        break;
}


if (!empty($_GET['MsgId'])) {
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('xxx', xxx))
      ->setUsername('xxx')
      ->setPassword('xxx');

    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

    $message = (new Swift_Message('Status SMS ' . $_GET['MsgId'] . '.'))
      ->setFrom(['xxx' => 'xxx'])
      ->setTo(['xxx' => 'xxx', 'xxx' => 'xxx'])
      // and here you use that variable we prepared :)
      ->setBody("ID Wiadomości : " . $_GET['MsgId'] . "Status Wiadomości" . $status . ".");

    $result = $mailer->send($message);

    echo 'OK';
 }
 else {
     echo 'Coś nie śmigło.';
 }
 exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

Converted the value received from $_GET to integer and added the `default` case value.

```
switch((int)$_GET['status'])
{
  case 403:
    echo 'sent';
    break;

  case 404:
    echo 'delivered';
    break;

 default:
    echo 'unknown status';
    break;
}
```